# Any new Reporting Controls in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, devexpress

I've been using DevExpress and CrystalReports for previous .NET versions.  I'm wondering if there are any native reporting controls for .NET 4.0, so I could do away with the 3rd party ones.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are MS Charting controls which are available in 3.5 ([here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en)) and also included in .NET 4.0.  In .NET 4.0, you'll want to reference System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.

Comment: Will these let me create PDFs?

Comment: Actually what I'm looking for is not charting, but plain text, to generate PDFs based off of a template.

Comment: Well, that's 5 minutes of your life you'll never get back.